# Android - Spinner doesn't get any selected value

Tags: android, android-spinner, selecteditem

I have a problem with my spinner. My spinner doesn't get any value when selected. I don't know what to do because I had applied so many answered and nothing affect on my code.
Here is my code. I am using retrofit2.

```
private List<String> listKotaNegara= new GetData().getListKota();

    spinnerJenisKamar = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelJenisKamar);
            dataAdapterJenisKamar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listJenisKamar);
            dataAdapterJenisKamar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerJenisKamar.setAdapter(dataAdapterJenisKamar);

            spinnerJenisKamar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

This is how I GetData from server.

```
public List<String> getListKota(){
    apiservice.getListKota("liskota").enqueue(new Callback<ListKotaResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListKotaResponse> call, Response<ListKotaResponse> response) {
            System.out.println("syalala : "+response.body()+", Response code; "+response.code()+", Response msg: "+response.message());
            final ListKotaResponse responses = response.body();
            List<ListNegara> listNegaras = responses.getListNegara();
            if(responses.getResult().equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
            {
                System.out.println("masuk if");

                for(ListNegara n: listNegaras)
                {
                    for(ListKotum k: n.getListKota()) {
                        listKotaNegara.add(k.getKota()+", "+n.getNegara());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListKotaResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("fail ",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
    return listKotaNegara;
}
```

Thank you very much :")

Comment: Is the Toast.makeText executed? But with item blank or it doesn't execute when selected an item?

Comment: Are you sure list listKotaNegara is not empty? getListKota method is asynchronous call, at this time list may be empty.  Set adapter in onResponse method.

Comment: @BrankVictoria The toast is not executed... Not at all... Not any blank either.

Comment: @Praveen listKotaNegara is not empty, i have check it out on the console. What kind of adapter i should set on?

Comment: Can you try to initialize your spinner like this: dataAdapterJenisKamar = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,listJenisKamar , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) For some reason when I work with spinners I do with this.

Comment: @BrankVictoria nay, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If your list is not empty, so something like this:

```
        private List<String> listKotaNegara= new GetData().getListKota();

        spinnerJenisKamar = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelJenisKamar);
        dataAdapterJenisKamar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listJenisKamar);
        dataAdapterJenisKamar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerJenisKamar.setAdapter(dataAdapterJenisKamar);

        spinnerJenisKamar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = listJenisKamar.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution. I must write the ArrayAdapter code inside the onResponse in Callback Retrofit 2.

Thank you for your support. :)